# Retrieve "property getter" from the property name

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection

I've been using this method to retrieve a property getter based on the name of the property.

```
public static Func<object> GetGetterFromProperty(object instance, string propertyName)
{
    var propInfo = instance.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredProperty(propertyName);
    var deleg = propInfo.GetMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<object>), instance);
    var action = (Func<object>)deleg;
    return action;
}
```

It returns a `Func<object>` since the type of the property is available only at runtime.

It works perfectly, but **ONLY** when the property is a reference type. When it's a value type, like int, it throws a `System.ArgumentException`

> Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security
>   transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type.

Comment: Convert your method to a genericc type

Comment: I cannot make a generic out of it. It's inherently dynamic!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct the delegate type using Reflection:

```
var delegateType = typeof(Func<>).MakeGenericType(propInfo.PropertyType);
var deleg = propInfo.GetMethod.CreateDelegate(delegateType, instance);
```

But ofcourse you can't cast it statically since you don't know it at compile time, you need to make the methods return type dynamic and return the delegate without casting.